# Haskell Vector Typeclass: Function of [a] -> [a] -> a

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Alright, I'm trying to wrap my head around typeclasses, and so I'm trying to define a typeclass for geometric vector operations. I managed to get it working for component-wise `+,-,*,/;` but I'm struggling with the dot product.

```
class GeomVector a where
  (>+) :: a -> a -> a
  (>-) :: a -> a -> a
  (>*) :: a -> a -> a
  (>/) :: a -> a -> a

  (>.) :: a -> a -> Double

data Vector a = Vec [a]
              deriving Show

instance (Fractional a) => GeomVector (Vector a) where
  (>+) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (+) u v
  (>-) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (-) u v
  (>*) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (*) u v
  (>/) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (/) u v

  (>.) (Vec u) (Vec v) = sum $ u >* v
```

Obviously my instance definition for (>.) won't work because the result is of type `Fractional a`, not `Double`.

But I don't know how to get this behavior from the declaration in the class.

What I'd *like* to do is:

```
class GeomVector [a] where
  (>.) :: [a] -> [a] -> a
```

But this is invalid because `[a]` is a type and not a type variable.

I wish I could explain this a little better, but I honestly don't understand enough to do so. Hopefully the code will make it a little more obvious what I'm struggling with.

Comment: I think you need another type variable to denote the type of the scalars, i.e. `class GeomVector a s where ... (>.) :: a -> a -> s`.

Comment: What you want is [Associated type synonyms](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#An_associated_type_synonym_example)

Comment: Your class declaration is flawed not only because of (>.) result type.

You attemtp to produce a dot product of ```u``` and ```v``` which are
lists, not instances of your class.

Comment: @Lambdageek Why synonyms? Isn't it just an associated type which is needed here? (```data Scalar a```)?

Comment: @DmitryDzhus `Scalar a` should be some existing type (for example, for  `instance GeomVector [a]` it should be `a`), not a brand new data type.

Comment: Have a look at the [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/vector-space) package.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option that could work:

```
class GeomVector v where
  (>+) :: Num a=> v a -> v a -> v a
  (>-) :: Num a=> v a -> v a -> v a
  (>*) :: Num a=> v a -> v a -> v a
  (>/) :: Fractional a=> v a -> v a -> v a
  (>.) :: Num a=> v a -> v a -> a

data Vector a = Vec { vecList :: [a] }
              deriving Show

instance GeomVector Vector where
  (>+) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (+) u v
  (>-) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (-) u v
  (>*) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (*) u v
  (>/) (Vec u) (Vec v) = Vec $ zipWith (/) u v

  (>.) u v = sum $ vecList (u >* v)
```

So all your instances of `GeomVector` will have a kind `* -> *` like the `Monad` class. And the types of the methods are not unnecessarily restricted to `Fractional` types just because you divide somewhere in there.

You might also consider making your class as small as possible (make `>.` a polymorphic function outside of the class) and whether what you really want is a type class to begin with. But all that depends on what you're designing, and I don't want to presume that I know better than you about that!

Comment: It's probably not possible to move `>.` out of the class, since it needs to know about the internal structure of each instance of `GeomVector` to do the sum.

Comment: right, sorry. So one option would be to make the class `class (Foldable v)=> GeomVector v` if that makes sense.

Comment: Furthermore, the pointwise operations all amount to `liftA2` for a zippy `Applicative`, and as such `Vector` might as well be `ZipList`.